# Why does Matlab ignore the first input always?

Tags: freemat

Like this for instance:

```
z = input('Enter z ')
t = input('Enter t ')
y = input('Enter y ')
```

It always prompts for `t` and `y` and ignores `z`.

I tried mixing them a bit and putting `y` in the front and so on and even changing the names of the variables, but **it always ignores the first one and asks for the others. Why is that?**

Comment: Works ok for me. Probably related to the code before this part. Can you share the whole code?

Comment: It seems that it worked after I started the .m file from the command prompt instead of using the run button...
Btw, there is no whole code, just this... I wanted to know why it happened.

Comment: It's also ok for me by using the run button.

Comment: Oh and I'm using FreeMat, is it different in that matter?
Couldn't afford the full Matlab software and the professor said FreeMat is sufficient.

Comment: Not quite sure. I think the problem probably results from the code before these three lines. Again share more code please.

Comment: Like I said I DID NOT use any code :/
The whole code is just as you see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug of `FreeMat`, see [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/freemat/bugs/549/) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/freemat/SA7VWjdci4o) (it runs well under MATLAB).